# variables (set dynamically) in aframe

Tags: aframe

in `aframe`, the values seem to be explicit strings:

`< a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere`

I want the values to be able to be set dynamically.

What is the "easiest" way to correctly implement the following `pseudocode` in a simple aframe web page:

> (1) var clr;
>
> (2) var pos;
>
> (3) evaluate clr and pos in functions
>
> (4) < a-sphere position=pos radius="1.25" color=clr shadow>

then, perhaps as in a `hand-coded animation`, continue to recompute `clr` and `pos` and show the `altered sphere`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind JS variables and DOM attributes with A-Frame out of the box. I recommend against that since it will make code harder to follow as complexity increases. The A-Frame way to do what you describe is defining your own component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent(“animate-position”,{
   tick: function () {
     var position = this.el.getAttribute(“position”);
     ... animation position calculation logic ...
     this.el.setAttribute(“position”, position);
   }
});
```

You can then assign the component to the entity

```
<a-sphere animate-position><a-sphere>
```

Comment: Thanks. There is some discussion of registering components here and on github (via  search on google). And a few pages in the APress WebVR book. Where in the aframe documentation itself will I find a discussion of registering components and other things I should know about aframe? The component definition is (usually is?) in three.js?

Comment: @qporit https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html , their website is full of of tutorials :)

Comment: Thanks. I see it now.